# How to politely decline a request for a job referral?

Tags: professionalism, networking, recommendation-letter

I am currently employed at an excellent company, and a colleague of mine from graduate school has repeatedly requested that I put his/her name forward as a recommended hire at my company.

For various reasons, this is not someone I would feel comfortable recommending for a job; even if it was with someone other than my current employer. The person is a good worker, but he/she can be very unpleasant to work with. What is the proper way to decline their request? He/she and I have many mutual colleagues in our professional network, so I would very much like to avoid creating any animosity with this person.

Comment: This question has been asked before. Generally, you refer the person anyway, but you tell the manager to stick the resume at the bottom of the pile.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I searched for the question but didn't find it.

Comment: No worries. I looked for a duplicate question, but couldn't find an exact match either. Anyway, that's the gist of the answer I can recall, if someone else wants to expand on it.

Comment: Or you could just tell them no. I used to have guys ask me to get them forestry jobs, and normally I'd say something along the lines of "Na... love you like a brother bro, but you got to admit you're a bit of a prick to work with, you'll give me a bad name." or "Na... you're a lazy bugger." They always took it alright.

Comment: I second the duplicate suggestion by @sleske and I've posted an answer on that question instead. It can use some more input.

Comment: Note @01101010101010: If you agree that this is a duplicate you can mark it as such yourself and recommend people that want to answer to do so on the original question.

Comment: @Lilienthal I agree that it's a duplicate and marked it as such -- thanks for letting me know.